# Python Generator triangle series

Tags: python

Just curious if I wanted to generate a triangular sequence of numbers (ie) when the user enters a number .the formula would be c*(c+1)/2 it returns 1 = 1 ,2 = 3 etc

the function

`def func(n=None,c=1)`

```
c would be a counter starting at 1

n would be the iterator
```

this is not homework,but I read about a question like this somewhere and I'm just trying to figure it out.

I need python code for the solution
thanks.

I'm using a while loop in a generator

Comment: You can only read generators by looping through them.

Comment: Another thing, I would use a `while True` loop appending things to a list, instead of using an iterator in the arguments.

Comment: sorry I meant a while loop...could you show me an example of using an iterator in an argument..just for learning

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know. I don't use them much, and find the properties that they have down-right strange. I believe that they are called Mutable Default Arguments though.

Comment: Could you please try to explain what the user input and the expected output is?

Comment: user enters a number 1 for example ..using a formula c*(c+1)/2 outputs 1...user enters 2 outputs 3...im just trying to figure out how to implement the n in an argument n=None,...c = the counter

Comment: n is the iterator ...i wonder would range(user input)work for the iterator...by that i mean the user decides how many times the loop is implemented .

Comment: The question asks for two inputs c and n..where c is 1..c is the counter and n  by default n is equal to none or null..it said to use a generator so I'd imagine I'd be using a while true statement as it says not to use a for loop...